# How to hide div when Textbox is focused?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, sidebar

I have a sidebar that is acting fine until i click on body.

**Happening in sidebar**

1. On click sidebar comes out and on mouseout it goes hidden.
2. when input box inside sidebar is focused then it is should not hide.
3. when input is not focused it follows step 1 nicely.

**What i want-**

When input is focused inside sidebar and at the same time when it is focused out because of body's input box focus then this sidebar should hide or on body click it should be hidden on action.

**jQuery-**

```
$(function(){

    $('.sidebar-alert').on('click',function(){
    $(this).animate({left:0},200);
    event.stopPropagation();   
}); 
    $('.sidebar-alert').on('mouseleave ',function(){

        if($(".focused-input").is(":focus"))
    {
        $('.sidebar-alert').show();
    }


        else
        {
            $('.sidebar-alert').animate({left:-295},200);

        }

    });
});
```

I am not able to bind mouseover and click for hiding sidebar.

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/VyWbj/2/)

**Updated fiddle**

Comment: 'When input is focused inside sidebar and at the same time another input box on body is focused, then this sidebar should hide or on body click it should be hidden on action.'  You cannot have focus to two elements simultaneously.

Comment: @Antonis, just updated my question, thanks for telling me about.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `blur` event for the input. That will take care of the issue that you have

```
 $(".focused-input").on('blur', function() {
     $('.sidebar-alert').animate({
          left: -295
     }, 200);
 });
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VyWbj/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can add one more event and selector in this part of code snippet like this:

```
$('.sidebar-alert, .focused-input').on('mouseleave focusout', function () {
    if ($(".focused-input").is(":focus")) {
        $('.sidebar-alert').show();
    } else {
        $('.sidebar-alert').animate({
            left: -295
        }, 200);
    }
});
```